# Deleting S3 object with + using CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

My S3 bucket (data-pop) has the following files

```
EDW_LastYear.tab+
EDW_LastYear.tab
EDW_ThisYear.tab+
```

I want to delete the weird files which have the + in them

Using AWS CLI, I try to delete them using the command

```
aws s3 rm s3://data-pop/EDW_LastYear.tab+
```

However it fails to delete the file. I only have read permissions on the S3 UI console, so I can't delete from there.

Deleting the entire bucket and then re-uploading the required files is not an option because this data is consistently being read in Production (except for those two files which are to be cleaned up)

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Does the access key/credentials you are using in CLI have delete permission?

Comment: As you have mentioned that you are able to delete "normal" objects, it may be due to the + sign which requires special handling. Please refer:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html

Answer (score 1):

We develop an alternative CLI for AWS: https://github.com/wallix/awless.

I just tried with it and you should be able to delete files with `+` in the name:

`awless delete s3object bucket=bucket-name name=file.txt+`

This should work if you have appropriate rights.